# How to bring an old question to the top of list?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

I had posted some questions for which I didnt get satisfactory answers. I want to again bring them to the top of list so that it can again gather some attention of the users. How can it be done ?

Comment: This question has been closed but it is worth pointing out that you appear to have only 3 questions on SO, two of which you have marked an answer as accepted and the third which has a 6 vote answer. If you aren't satisfied with an answer the don't mark it answered since that greatly lowers the chance of new answers. With the 6 vote answer that looks like it is pretty good already.